# Product weight based price option required in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I need an option to set price based on the product weight.

For eg, let us consider the senario of gold/silver ornaments.
 1 gm gold ornament rate is calculated based on the current market price of gold rate.
 ie., product rate = weight * current metal rate.

How this can be done in prestashop?
Any one kindly help me. . .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is by using the attributes to create combinations.

For this, you can:

- Go to **Catalog > Attributes and Values**
- Create a **new Attribute** (e.g. Metal type)
- Create new values for that attribute: **Gold, Silver**
- Now go to **Catalog > Products** and choose your product
- Choose the **Combination tab** and from there, you can use the **Product
  combinations generator** and specify everything you need: price,
  reference, weight.

That's it..! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I actually need two types of pricing strategy in shopping cart.
1) Fixed price - MRP
2) Unfixed price - metal (product) weight * current metal rate.
Is there possibilities to have both pricing strategy in prestashop.

Comment: @DSP Ok, but what's the point of having the fixed prices and Unfixed for a particular product? It that because the market price trends? Yes, you can do it. Just follow the steps on my previous answer and then use the products combination generator to define the values for each type [metal (product) weight] and the current metal rate.

Something like this : http://xomf.com/bgflg

Comment: thanks, Actually two types of products dealing in the same shop and two separate pricing strategy for each items. 
for eg: 
     1) metals (silver/Gold bar) - price vary according to market price. 
     2) gift item (like medal, toys) - fixed MRP
and one more thing where i have to enter the weight of the product in feature or in attribute.

Comment: Yes you can do that bro. See the 7th Field in the image i have uploaded. It has an area to add the weight and it's impact on price.